# Class reference to an object instantiated by a literal

Tags: c++

What is happening here?

```cpp
struct A {
    A (int){std::cout<<'A';}
};
const A& a = 3;
```

My assumption is since the literal `3` is an *rvalue*, *temporary materialization conversion* is applied. A temporary object is created by calling the constructor thus printing `A` and the reference is bound to the resulting object.

Comment: If the questions is "am I right" then the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `a` is an lvalue reference [[dcl.ref]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#2) to a const-qualified class type, the initializer expression `3` is a prvalue [[expr.prim.literal]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.literal#1) of non-class type `int` [[lex.icon]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.icon#2) that is neither reference-related nor reference-compatible to `const A` [[dcl.init.ref]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4). Therefore, [[dcl.init.ref]/5.4.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.4.1) would seem to apply. There is a converting constructor [[class.conv.ctor]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor#def:converting_constructor), which will be used to convert `3` to a prvalue of type `const A`, which is then used to initialize the reference. This time around, the intializer expression now is a prvalue of type `const A`, which is reference related to `const A`. Thus, [[dcl.init.ref]/5.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.3) should apply, which will perform temporary materialization [[conv.rval]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval). The lifetime of the temporary object created in the process will be extended [[class.temporary]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#6) since it is being bound to the reference `a` which lives in global namespace scope…

Answer (score 0):

implicit conversion was occured. it converted from `3` to an object of `A`, then reference `a` point to this object.

better practice is add keyword `explicit` in constructor which take only one parameter like this. then no implicit conversion happen. then below code will throw error.

refer: 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-35/

https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/9-13-converting-constructors-explicit-and-delete/

```
struct A {
   explicit A (int){std::cout<<'A';}
};
const A& a = 3;
```